# Failing To Discover Bluetooth LE Service Advertisement in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheralmanager

I have created two iOS apps; one a Bluetooth LE peripheral that advertises a service, and one a Bluetooth LE central that scans for the advertised service. The peripheral is running on my iPhone5s, and the central is running on my iPad Mini. I initially set the central up to scan for the specific advertised service, but later changed it to listen to any service. In either case, the iPad Mini app acting as a central never detects any advertised service. I am uncertain whether its a problem with the way I setup the peripheral manager to advertise, or if its a problem with the way I setup the central manager to scan, or a device configuration problem. Please offer suggestions or tests I can perform to get this working.

The following is the relevant code for the iPhone5s app acting as a peripheral:

```
CBPeripheralManager *peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil];

CBUUID *immediateAlertServiceUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString: IMMEDIATE_ALERT_SERVICE_UUID];
CBUUID *alertLevelCharacteristicUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString: ALERT_LEVEL_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID];
CBUUID *myCustomCharacteristicUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString: MY_CUSTOM_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID];

alertLevelCharacteristic =
[[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:alertLevelCharacteristicUUID
                                   properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead
                                        value: nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
myCustomCharacteristic =
[[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:myCustomCharacteristicUUID
                                   properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead
                                        value: nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];

NSArray *myCharacteristics = @[alertLevelCharacteristic, myCustomCharacteristic];

// Now setup the service
myService = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:immediateAlertServiceUUID primary:YES];

// Finally, associate the characteristic with the service. This is an array of characteristics
myService.characteristics = myCharacteristics;

[peripheralManager addService:myService];

... wait for user to push button to start advertising ...

// Start Advertising
[peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : @"My Service",
                                       CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[myService.UUID] }];
```

And here are the necessary delegate methods. NOTE: delegate method peripheralManagerDidUpdateState fires and indicates that "CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready" (same is true on the central side). Delegate method peripheralManager:didAddService:error fires without error (see output below). And delegate method peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising:error fires without an error). Here is the service info printed from didAddService:

```
<CBMutableService: 0x17008efb0 Primary = YES, UUID = 1802, Included Services = (null), Characteristics = (
"<CBMutableCharacteristic: 0x1702c1500 UUID = 2A06, Value = (null), Properties = 0x2, Permissions = 0x1, Descriptors = (null), SubscribedCentrals = (\n)>",
"<CBMutableCharacteristic: 0x1702c15e0 UUID = 66E613B5-7225-42C6-A9C2-11FADAE62899, Value = (null), Properties = 0x2, Permissions = 0x1, Descriptors = (null), SubscribedCentrals = (\n)>")>
```

CBPeripheralManager Delegate Methods (sorry for all the code, just trying to be complete.):

```
- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {

// Determine the state of the peripheral
if ([peripheral state] == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
    NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");
}
else if ([peripheral state] == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
    NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");
}
else if ([peripheral state] == CBPeripheralManagerStateUnauthorized) {
    NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
}
else if ([peripheral state] == CBPeripheralManagerStateUnknown) {
    NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");
}
else if ([peripheral state] == CBPeripheralManagerStateUnsupported) {
    NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");
}
}

- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral
        didAddService:(CBService *)service
                error:(NSError *)error {

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error publishing service: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    return;
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Hurray! Your Service has been successfully published as: %@", service);
}
}

- (void)peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral
                                   error:(NSError *)error {

if (error == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Your service is now advertising");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"In peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising: Your service advertising failed with error: %@", error);
}

}
```

And here is the relevant central code that runs on the iPad Mini:

```
// Scan for all available CoreBluetooth LE devices
NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:IMMEDIATE_ALERT_SERVICE_UUID]];

CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

//[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:nil];
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
self.centralManager = centralManager;
```

And here is one of the Central delegate methods. Except for centralManagerDidUpdateState:, none of the delegate methods fire.

```
// CBPeripheralDelegate - Invoked when you discover the peripheral's available services.
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Did Discover Services");
    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
    }
}

// CBCentralManagerDelegate - This is called with the CBPeripheral class as its main input parameter. This contains most of the information there is to know about a BLE peripheral.
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
NSLog(@"Did Discover Peripheral");
NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
if (![localName isEqual:@"My Service"]) {
    // We found the Device
    [self.centralManager stopScan];
    self.myPeripheral = peripheral;
    peripheral.delegate = self;
    [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}
}
```

As a final note, I question whether BLE even works on my devices. I loaded a couple different iBeacon apps on the iPhone and iPad Mini to see if I can get the two devices to recognize iBeacons (one transmits, one receives), but they did not discover iBeacons either. I also tried with two iPhones. I also turned Bluetooth off then on. I also tried powering the devices off/on. Both devices are running in the foreground. Still no luck. Please help.

Comment: When do you scan? It's not clear if you wait for the [peripheralManager state] to be "ok". Also, does LightBlue see your devices? Does 2 apps with two Ligthblue devices, it works?

Comment: @Larme I have tried starting up the Central first and starting up the Peripheral first. Neither approach works. Question: once the scan is started, doesn't it continually scan (i.e. does it matter which starts up first)?  I have not tried LightBlue. I will try that now.

Comment: @Larme Ok, I tried LightBlue. It does detect the service being advertised from my iPhone. So this would suggest that there is a problem with the Central scan. Do you see anything wrong with the code I have in the Central for scanning and detecting the service?

Comment: Where is the `centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:` method?

Comment: @Larme I just added it to the Question above. I never get to that delegate method either

Comment: What's the state of CBCentralManager state when you start the scan?

Comment: @Larme Ah. Thats it. I was scanning immediately after initializing the Central Manager. When I moved the start of the scan after the centralManagerDidUpdateState indicates the BLE is powered on, it works. Thanks.

Comment: There should be a message in the console saying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll concatenate all the comments here:

Using apps like *LightBlue* or *BLE Utility* can help you to find if your issue is on the peripheral side or central one, since you're developing both sides yourself.

Before looking for `CBServices`, you have to connect to a `CBPeripheral`.
Method that you did show before hand, and seems that it wasn't obvious.

Also, before starting a scan with the `CBCentralManager` you have to check its `state`, and it has to be `CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn`.